# Como estratificar/dividir um data.frame conforme categorias de uma variável no R?

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, data.frame

Estou rodando um modelo de regressão linear no R e gostaria de realizar a análise estratificada segundo categorias de uma `variável X` com 4 categorias (`X1`, `X2`, `X3` e `X4`).

Pensei em estratificar o `data.frame` pelas categorias de X, assim eu teria 4 `data.frames` e rodaria o mesmo modelo para cada categoria.

Tentei a função:

```
X1=data.frame[which(data.frame$X==1), ]
```

mas resultou em um `data.frame X1` com `0` observações (linhas), apesar de aparecer o nome das colunas.

O que sugerem para corrigir este erro? Obrigada.

Comment: As categorias de `X` são `X1`, `X2`, `X3` e `X4` ou `1`, `2`, `3` e `4`?

Comment: As categorias são X1, X2, X3 e X4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias formas de rodar várias regressões por categoria no R. Vou te mostrar como fazer com as funções base do R e com o `dplyr`. Como exemplo, vamos usar a base de dados `mtcars`.

Suponha que você queira rodar a regressão `mpg ~ disp + hp` para cada nível da variável `cyl` de `mtcars` (são 3 categorias).

Primeiramente, você pode usar a função `split()` para construir uma lista com três `data.frames` diferentes, um para cada categoria:

```
data.frame_por_categoria <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

Agora, basta usar `lapply()` para aplicar a regressão em cada `data.frame`:

```
modelos <- lapply(data.frame_por_categoria, function(x) lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = x))
```

O resultado, `modelos` é uma lista com as três regressões. Para acessar o primeiro modelo:

```
modelos[[1]]
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + hp, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp           hp  
   43.04006     -0.11954     -0.04609
```

Também é possível fazer a mesma coisa com o pacote `dplyr`.

Você manda agrupar pela categoria e depois utiliza função `do()` para rodar a regressão, colocando um ponto `.` onde o `data.frame` precisaria entrar:

```
library(dplyr)
resultado <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(modelo = lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = .))
```

O `resultado` da operação é um `data.frame` com uma coluna chamada modelo, e cada elemento dessa coluna é a regressão. Para acessar o primeiro modelo:

```
resultado$modelo[[1]]
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + hp, data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp           hp  
   43.04006     -0.11954     -0.04609
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, Carlos! Deu super certo!

Comment: Por nada @Naomi, se você acha que a resposta atendeu, você também pode aceita-la! Abs